# Codeigniter $this->zip->download() not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, download, zip

I have a directory full of pdf files on the server which are uploaded by the users.

I'm trying to create a method that will download the entire directory as zip file.

I'm using CodeIgniter. The simple code worked fine when the directory's weight was about 100MB. But now when the directory's weight is about 600MB, it's just not working.
(I am getting a white empty screen after about 10 seconds of loading).

Notice that I'm new to CodeIgniter...

```
public function download()
{
    $this->load->library('zip');
    $this->zip->read_dir('pdf/');
    $this->zip->download('Download.zip'); 


}
```

Thank you!

Comment: In your php.ini you may have to increase `max_execution_time` and/or `memory_limit`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of it. I'll try it immediately.

Comment: Let us know how you get on, also don't forget to restart apache after changing any settings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was working okay before then you may have to change some settings in your php.ini.  Try increasing `max_execution_time` and/or `memory_limit`

Comment: @TzahiSerruya what did you increase them too?  Also check your log files for any errors

Comment: I suddenly realize with phpinfo() that the changes in php.ini I made are not working. What could be the problem?
I changed /etc/php5/apache/php.ini file, saved it and restarted apache. why in phpinfo() I see only 128MB Memory limit??

Comment: Make sure you edited the correct php.ini.  What is displayed next to "Loaded Configuration File" and "Configuration File" in the phpinfo()?

Comment: lol! you are correct. it's not the correct file. dumb me. NOW IT IS WORKING. THANK YOU!

Comment: BTW, in order to zip a 500MB directory I needed to set Memory_limit of the server to 1540MB(!). With 1GB it didn't work. Not too efficient...

Comment: Yeah, I'd find another way of doing that.  Probably best to use a cron job or something

Answer (score 0):

You could try to separate the zip file creation and the download process. It may minimize the memory and time limit requirements.

First create the zip file, and the redirects to the file to dowload it.

Let us know how you did it work at last.

Comment: Thought of it, just loved the simplicity of this code and was trying to stay with this way. 
If I'll not find any way to get it work I'll try your suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Its maybe cause of your server handling capacity. Try increasing max_execution_time and/or memory_limit in PHP.INI file in your server configuration.

in linux/centos -> /etc/php.ini

in ubuntu -> /etc/apache2/../php.ini

**Note :** Don't forget to restart your apache/httpd server

Linux/centos -> sudo service httpd restart

Ubunut -> sudo service apache2 restart